# Delete rows through eloquent relations

Tags: php, laravel

I have tables "projects" and "tasks". Each project could have multiple tasks so its a one-to-many relationship.

onDelete cascade is not working for me

When I delete a project, then go tasks, I get an error.
So I need that when you delete a project it deletes all the tasks in relation with this.
This are my migrations;

```
 Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('task_id')->default($value=null)->unsigned();

            $table->integer('proj_id')->nullable()->default($value=null)->foreign('proj_id')->references('proj_id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('proj_id')->nullable()->default($value=null)->foreign('proj_id')->references('proj_id')->on('tasks')->onDelete('cascade');
```

And these are my models;

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'proj_id';
    protected $fillable = ['proj_title','proj_desc','client_id','created_by'];



    public function client (){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
    public function task (){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
    }
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'task_id';

    protected $fillable = ['task_title','task_desc','status','priority','person_id','proj_title','proj_id','created_by'];

    public function project(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project','proj_id');
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get? Or the records are just not deleted?

Comment: The records are not deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have good reason to name the columns as you have, I would suggest following convention and changing your migrations to...

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('project_id');
    // other columns...

    $table->foreign('project_id')
        ->references('id')->on('projects')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});

Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    // other columns...
});
```

Increments should not have a default as it is the primary ID and is also unsigned by default.

You will need to update the relationship definitions in your models if you make the above changes. This should remove your error.

As a little extra, quite often you will want more functionality than simply cascading a delete. Laravel offers events and listeners which can be used to get the behaviour you require - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events. This explains how you can achieve what you need by creating a model observer.

I would recommend taking the time to get familiar with the above. Although you can also get the same results by adding the following method to your `Project` class,

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function(Project $project) {
        $project->tasks()->delete();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look into that. I added that bit of code but I get "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tasks.project_proj_id' in 'where clause' "

Comment: Ah, either update your `Project` method `task()` to `tasks()` (which better describes the relationship), or change the code I posted from `tasks()` to `task()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just need the foreign key on proj_id of the tasks table and not the other way round, so first remove the foreign key on the primary column of projects.

Furthermore, the column type of the foreign on tasks table must match the primary key on the projects table. You need to use *unsignedInteger* as *increments* on the projects table will create an unsigned auto increment integer primary key.

```php
$table->unsignedInteger('proj_id')->nullable()->default(null);
$table->foreign('proj_id')->references('proj_id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Then rerun the migration and it should work well. If you have any error, update your answer